# Is it acceptable to use a tilde symbol to sign your name?

Tags: punctuation, formality

Should the tilde symbol (~) be used to sign your name? It seems quite commonplace on Internet forums but I don't believe I've ever seen it used in books.

Comment: It might be worth noting sites like Twitter that prefix user names with characters automatically in certain cases, such as with `@` and `#`. The user isn't always in full control on the web. Do you have any examples?

Comment: I've only saw that in Wikipedia...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hyphen, standing in a for a dash, is the more-common punctuation for signing and attributing quotes. - The Raven

Answer (score 5):

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aSign_your_posts_on_talk_pages), four tildes are used to sign a post. This character sequence will be recognised by the software and turned into the user name and a date stamp. This does not mean that a tilde is a valid character to sign your name elsewhere, web or paper.

Answer (score -3):

in the mathematics language the tilde means "equivalent to", so at the end of a signature it may not be proper. However it still looks nice I don't see anything wrong with it can't hurt to stand out and be creative, right? Also, what if it looks to some like it means you're equal to everybody. . .  if you perceive it that way? Were all one anyway and if u put it after a smiley it looks like a funny goatee:)~

Comment: I thought it meant approximately?

Comment: @Medica: It appears that the tilde, like many, many symbols in mathematics, is used to represent several distinct concepts. (Even π is overloaded...) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Mathematics

Comment: @sumelic - Thanks! I would never have known that. And thanks for the link.